# Visio, SharePoint list view

Tags: sharepoint-online, list-view, view, visio

I am using **Visio 2013** with external data. I am linking a **SharePoint Online list view**.
Why I do not see the *correct fields* in Visio? 
 
I selected a list view but I see other fields not those in the view.

 (I wish to see some folder fields)